# Using SetConsoleTitleW(LPCWSTR) to set the console title, but console title resulting in random UNICODE characters

Tags: c++, unicode, dev-c++

I am working on a Console Application project.

I wanted to change the title of the console to something else, so I used `SetConsoleTitleW(LPCWSTR)`, which accepts `wchar_t` string input.

But when I try using the function in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  SetConsoleTitleW(L"Bank Application");
  return 0;
}
```

My code is very straightforward, as I have *just* started the project with a simple `WINAPI` function.

However, this generates the following

[image: console]

Which consists of random `UNICODE` characters in the title of the console.

Any issue with the buffer? My code is very simple and straightforward, as far as I can see.

I'm using Embarcadero DevC++ with TDM-GCC 9.2.0 64-bit compiler, Release.

**EDIT** : Using `SetConsoleA(LPCSTR)` produces the same thing.

Comment: I cannot replicate your error (tdm64-1 version 10.3.0). It sounds like you have an odd font set for your title bars. (Korean?)

Comment: For my font set, I do not speak korean, or understand any of korean, I speak plain english, and only have english fonts installed.

Comment: It can either be a console buffer issue, or some issue in the unicode buffer.

Comment: Neither of those should affect the console title. My only other thought is what your locale and/or code page is set to? (And Windows comes pre-installed with fonts that have Korean glyphs, BTW.)

Comment: Is that your *exact* code?

Comment: Does console title change as a result of `SetConsoleTitleW` invocation? I mean if you set a break point there, does it look ok initially? Does `SetConsoleTitleW` actually invoke WinAPI function?

Comment: I would expect mojibake to be longer than that result. Indeed I seem to get 䉡湫⁁灰汩捡瑩潮 with UTF-16 BE and 慂歮䄠灰楬慣楴湯 with UTF-16 LE unless I messed up the conversion.

Comment: Does the same glitch happen if you run your program from a regular console, not using the debugger console? In other words, if you just run CMD.EXE first, then change the directory to where your executable is located (type `CD /D "C:\The Folder Your App Is Located"`), and run it (type `"my app name.exe"`)? Maybe the Dev-C++'s debugger is somehow interfering with the `SetConsoleTitle` call?

Comment: your process exited. SetConsoleTitle is only in effect until your program ends, and then it restores the original title.

Comment: Are we being trolled about soup? (The text is Chinese)

Comment: I've tried the code in a Windows Terminal, but the title doesn't even change!

Answer (score 1):

From microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle

> When the process terminates, the system restores the original console
> title.

Your screenshot shows your process has terminated. Why your console title shows those characters has nothing to do with your program.

Answer (score 1):

You screenshot suggests that you are not using a true Windows console. `SetConsoleTitle` is only intended to be used in a true Windows console, and using it with any other *terminal emulator* will just have undefined results.

I have slightly changed you code to

```
...
SetConsoleTitleW(L"Bank Application");
Sleep(5000);
return 0;
...
```

in order to have 5 seconds to see what happens. Then I tried it inside a plain console and correctly saw the changed title. But I also tried it from a MSYS2 terminal... and nothing happened at all.

I could not identify you terminal application from its icon, but I would still bet a coin that it is the culprit

Comment: that's a normal conhost.exe in Windows 10 which is the windows console

Comment: the icon definitely indicates it is not a windows console.  I suspect it is some kind of console used by your debugger

Comment: @GarrGodfrey The icon on the left is the default icon for all apps that don't have an icon

Comment: sure...but conhost.exe has an icon. It looks like [C:\]